# How do i turn an imported list from txt that is a string into an actual list?

Tags: python

I have this code

```
f= open('data\\party.txt', 'r')
my_party = f.read()
f.close
my_party = json.loads(my_party)
```

party.txt contains the following

```
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

I want this to be imported as the list it is. But it get turned into a string.

Comment: What "format" is the text file using? Is it "Python" or some other / home-brew "format"? The easiest solution would probably be to use *actual* JSON..

Comment: Your .txt file is not json, first of all.